# Como accesar la variable super-global $_FILES correctamente

Tags: php

Soy fanático del código limpio y he encontrado que dentro de las reglas controversiales de PHP Mess Detector, se considera que accesar a variables super globales directamente es una mala practica.

Para el caso de ***$_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SERVER y $_ENV***, el acceso a las variables super globales se puede realizar con la función filter_input (***INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER o INPUT_ENV***) por ejemplo:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var_name') en lugar de $_POST['var_name']
```

Sin embargo no encuentro la manera para no accesar directamente la variable super global $_FILES.

Sugieren encapsular el acceso y he probado hacerlo de estas dos maneras sin resultado ya que el PHPMD sigue mostrando el problema.

```
class Files
{
    public $vars;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->vars = &$_FILES;
    }
}
```

y

```
class Files
{

    public static function get($name ,$key)
    {
        return (isset($_FILES[$name])) ? $_FILES[$name][$key] : null;
    }
}
```

Sé que funciona el código accesando directamente la variable super global pero, como les digo, soy fanático del código limpio. Cualquier idea es bienvenida

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Una opción sería crear una clase envoltorio (wrapper) a través de la cual manejarías las diferentes peticiones ([ver aquí](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/218673)). Para refinar la clase  te puedes inspirar en otros frameworks, por ejemplo [la clase `Request`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) de Symfony.

Comment: Que tal @A.Cedano gracias por tu respuesta, ya cree el envoltorio que sugieres y funciona a la perfección, sin embargo al crear la instancia de la clase Request ($request = new Request($_FILES);) El PHPMD sigue enviando el mensaje que se esta accesando la variable super-global $_FILES

Comment: Realmente no tengo experiencia en el uso de Mess, pero parece bastante claro que para ellos el acceso directo a una super global forma parte del grupo de reglas controversiales y aconsejan el uso de algún framework para ello: *Accessing a super-global variable directly is considered a bad practice. These variables should be encapsulated in objects that are provided by a framework, for instance.* ([ver aquí](https://phpmd.org/rules/#controversial-rules)). Se interpreta que no hay forma directa de evitar advertencias a no ser que uses algún framework.